# Help with $\lim\limits_{x \to 0^+}{x^a}{\ln x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

> Evaluate $$\lim\limits_{x \to 0^+}{x^a}{\ln x}$$

I used L'Hopital rule till $\Large \lim\limits_{x \to 0^+}{\frac{x^{a-2}}{-a}}$ but I can't go any further. Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: What is $\;a\;$ ? You need to know this if you're to use l'H's rule

Comment: 'a' is a constant

Comment: The limit is $0$. You can plug in 0.

Comment: Yes, I gathered that @Fad: what kind of constant, though?

Comment: @Timbuc Not really sure.. the qn just stated that 'a' was a constant.

Comment: Thanks @Alizter for your help - So I just plug 0 into my current solution?

Comment: "Just plugging zero" in your solution may cause you problems, @Fad: how would you justify that? I think you must divide the problem in  two cases. Look below.

Comment: Thanks for all the help :D

Comment: @Alizter: How can you plug-in $0$ to $\ln{X}$?

Comment: @Fad, I saw your intended edit of my answer. Please take into account that in advanced mathematics we're used to take $\;\log x\;$ as what you denote by $\;\ln x:=\log_ex\;$ : both ways are the napierian or natural logarithm at base $\;e\;$ .

Comment: @barakmanos After L'H

Answer (score 5):

If $\;a\le 0\;$:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}x^a\log x=-\infty\;,\;\;\text{since}\;\;x^a\xrightarrow[x\to 0^+]{}\begin{cases}1\;,\;\;a=0\\\infty\;,\;\;a<0\end{cases}\;\;,\;\;\log x\xrightarrow[x\to 0^+]{}-\infty$$

If $\;a>0\;$ , directly by l'Hospital's rule:

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\log x}{\frac1{x^a}}\stackrel{\text{l'H}}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\frac1x}{-a\frac1{x^{a+1}}}=-\frac1a\lim_{x\to 0^+}x^a=0$$

Comment: $(x^{-a})'=-ax^{-a-1}$, isn't it?

Comment: Indeed so, @mathlove . Thanks, edited.

Comment: You are welcome. nice explanation.